# Bootstrap : Accordion Row : Change expand-collapse icons when there are MULTIPLE ROWS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, icons, accordion

I am having one table with some accordion rows.
I want to change expand-collapse icons on row expand-collapse
I got success for 1 row. But when I try it for multiple rows, my code works badly and clashing with other rows

Please help me out if anybody is having solution

```
var flag = true;
$('.togglebutton').click(function() {
        if (flag == true) {
            this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "../images/minus.png";
            flag = false;
        } else {
            this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "../images/plus.png";
            flag = true;
        }
    })

<tr class="clickable apply-max-width">
                            <td class="table-tr1-td1 togglebutton"><b aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion"><img src="../images/plus.png"/></b></td>

                            <td>abcd@gmail.com</td>
                            <td colspan="2">WD100165</td>
                            <td>2/1/2017</td>
                            <td>YES</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <div id="accordion" class="accordion collapse data-found">

                                    <table class="table table-striped data-table-inner-disabled div-found">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th class="">Application</th>
                                                <th class="">App Role</th>
                                                <th>Workflow Status</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv"><img src="../images/delete_1.png" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv">Portal</td>
                                                <td>User</td>
                                                <td>Pending Approval</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv"><img src="../images/delete_1.png" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv">SSR</td>
                                                <td>User</td>
                                                <td>Provisioned</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="clickable apply-max-width">
                            <td class="table-tr1-td1 togglebutton"><b aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#accordion2"><img src="../images/plus.png"/></b></td>

                            <td>abcd@gmail.com</td>
                            <td colspan="2">WD100165</td>
                            <td>2/1/2017</td>
                            <td>YES</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td colspan="2">
                                <div id="accordion2" class="accordion collapse data-found">

                                    <table class="table table-striped data-table-inner-disabled div-found">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th class="">Application</th>
                                                <th class="">App Role</th>
                                                <th>Workflow Status</th>

                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv"><img src="../images/delete_1.png" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv">Portal</td>
                                                <td>User</td>
                                                <td>Pending Approval</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv"><img src="../images/delete_1.png" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                                                <td class="application-User-inv">SSR</td>
                                                <td>User</td>
                                                <td>Provisioned</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the flag state for each accordion. A simple way to do this is using jQuery data()...

```
$('.togglebutton').data("flag",1);
$('.togglebutton').click(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.data("flag") == 1) {
        $t.find('img')[0].src = "//placehold.it/40/?text=M";
        $t.data("flag",0);
    } else {
        $t.find('img')[0].src = "//placehold.it/40/?text=P";
        $t.data("flag",1);
    }
})
```

http://codeply.com/go/e49vQb4wE4

Comment: This is not perfectly working for me.. Is there any change I need to do with my HTML code? AND what is "//placehold.it/40/?text=M ?

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. Those are just other placeholder images because you didn't provide the actual links for plus and minus images. Clarify what's not working.

Comment: now it's working.. It was my own fault.. Thanks a ton

Comment: Can you look into this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43886146/bootstrap-collapsible-row-hide-show-row-which-we-are-expanding